# Wordpress FTP not working on my Linode VPS

Tags: wordpress, vps

I'm having trouble updating my plugins through wp-admin on my Linode VPS. I can connect via FTP client and write to any directory but when I try the same username / pass but with the hostname set to localhost in wp-admin, I get:

```
 ERROR: There was an error connecting to the server, Please verify the settings are correct.
```

Is there a setting I'm overlooking?

Comment: have you go for permalink setting...?

Comment: Yes, custom permalink "/%year%/%postname%.html"

Comment: go again to settings->permalinks and save it just without doing any changes, just save it. and check out, its working or not.

Comment: Thanks but no, it didn't do it. Maybe I should mention I'm running VSFTP

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If WordPress is asking you for FTP information, you need to look at your file ownership & permissions. Your WordPress files should be owned by the same user as your web server (most likely www-data) and that user needs to have permission to write to those files. If those are set correctly, WordPress will be able to access the filesystem directly and not need to go through FTP for any installs or upgrades.

I'm working on a plugin called [Upgrade First Aid](https://github.com/daveross/upgrade-first-aid) which should help with troubleshooting these sorts of issues in WordPress 3.6 and higher. You can download the latest version [here](https://github.com/daveross/upgrade-first-aid/archive/master.zip) and upload it to your site. Activate it, and it will add a new menu item under "tools" to check your file permissions.

Comment: Amazing. I just chown'd everything in the public_html directory and now it's perfect.

Answer (score 4):

You need to modify the ownership.  Try this command:

```
chown -R www-data ~/public/example.com/public
```